# I have a HTML form used to update content in my DB, if I type in a single quote in the input field of my form, the sql update fails

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have a very simple form, when I type into the forms input fields, the data gets passed into a php script and it adds the data to my db. However if I enter something with a apostrophe or single quote, that breaks the query and the data does not get added into my db.

Form Code

```
<form method="POST" action="#">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Title: </label><br><input type="text" name="title1" placeholder="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($deal1title); ?>"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>Description: </label><br><textarea style="height: 200px;" name="desc1" placeholder="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($deal1desc); ?>"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label>Price: </label><br><input type="text" name="price1" placeholder="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($deal1price); ?>"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label>Include: </label><br><input type="text" name="include1" placeholder="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($deal1inc); ?>"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label>Not Include: </label><br><input type="text" name="notinc1" placeholder="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($deal1noinc); ?>"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Save"></td>
            </tr>

        </table>

    </form>
```

PHP Code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){

    $getTitle1=$_POST["title1"];
    $getDesc1=$_POST["desc1"];
    $getPrice1=$_POST["price1"];
    $getInc1=$_POST["include1"];
    $getNoInc=$_POST["notinc1"];
        //Set Title
        if(!empty($getTitle1)){
        mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE specials SET title='$getTitle1' WHERE id=1");
        }
        //Set Description
        if(!empty($getDesc1)){
            mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE specials SET description='$getDesc1' WHERE id=1");    
        }
        //Set Price
        if(!empty($getPrice1)){
        mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE specials SET price='$getPrice1' WHERE id=1");
        }
        //Set Include
        if(!empty($getInc1)){
            mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE specials SET include='$getInc1' WHERE id=1");
        }
        //Set noinclude
        if(!empty($getNoInc)){
            mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE specials set notinclude='$getNoInc' WHERE id=1");
        }


    }
```

Comment: Try using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` which you should already, since you're open to SQL injection.

Comment: Would I use it to wrap round the variable I am trying to set inside of my query?

Comment: Yes. For example: `$var=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['var']);` - `$con` being your DB connection variable. Using [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) will also help.

Comment: I tried $getDesc1=  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["desc1"]); but I got the following error: Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [<a href='function.mysql-real-escape-string'>function.mysql-real-escape-string</a>]: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/sfloresw/public_html/ecuador/admin.php on line 20

Comment: Not `mysql_real_escape_string` you left out the `i` this is what I wrote `$var=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['var']);` plus the connection variable.

Comment: Looks like that got rid of the original error code, this is the new error code that I got:  Warning: mysqli_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/sfloresw/public_html/ecuador/admin.php on line 30

Comment: Did you not include your DB connection variable? That's the problem. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This is why you have to be careful about escaping data that your putting into your queries or preferably using prepared statments. Your code is currently vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

The quick and dirty way to do this is to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` on all of the variables going into your query to escape any special characters. For example:

```
mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE specials SET description='".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $getDesc1)."' WHERE id=1");
```

---

A better solution is to use prepared statements with PHP's PDO driver instead. For example:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE specials SET description=? WHERE id=1");
$stmt->execute(array($getDesc1));
```

PDO handles all of the data sanitation for you thereby fixing both your problem and preventing SQL injection attacks at the same time.